# What is the terminology for half interval?

Tags: inequality, terminology

All $x$ where $a \leq x \leq b$, i.e. $[a, b]$ is an **interval**, or “range“, commonly named.

But all $x$ where $x \geq a$, “i.e. $[a, \infty]$” is **not** called an **open interval** –  it is a term for all $x$ where $a \lt x \lt b$, i.e. $(a, b)$, or **half-open interval** for $[a, b)$, or for $(a, b]$.

So, how is the infinite “set” of numbers on a half-line of the number line named? I'd guess e.g. **“half interval”**, but I don't see it to be in use. (And I'd be more happy for a “trivial” plain English name, like “range” for interval, than e.g. complicated an **“interval with an [infinite endpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Infinite_endpoints)”**.)

### UPDATE

#### Simple English

Let's say I'm talking about natural numbers.

1 to 5, or 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 this is an interval, or range (1–5).

Anything greater or equal 7, or 7, 8, 9, … (to infinity), this is what?

Comment: I've heard intervals of the form $(x,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,x]$ and similar where at least one of the endpoints is $\pm \infty$ called "*Infinite intervals.*"

Comment: As an aside, unless you are working in the extended real numbers, $\infty$ is not treated as a number and as such is not included *in* the interval, so square brackets are not appropriate.  The set $\{x\in \Bbb R~:~x\geq a\}$ is written instead as $[a,\infty)$ with a parenthesis on the right.

Comment: Let's say I'm talking about discrete, natural numbers, so I'm not interested in the science of infinity.

Comment: I don't understand what your most recent comment is in reference to.  If you were talking about natural numbers then you wouldn't be talking about intervals in the sense you are above and concepts like "open" and "closed" wouldn't be applicable (*in the usual sense*)... rethink that comment.

Comment: @JMoravitz I mentioned "open interval" because it is what I would use as a "trivial name" for the debated entity, pereceived by me to be synonymous to "half interval", but unfortunately alredy taken for "intervals" as well (but for real number intervals, with different infinitesimality properties ad its boundaries). (Sorry for lame terminology)

Comment: Finite intervals: $[a,b],(a,b),[a,b),(a,b]$ with both $a$ and $b$ finite with $a<b$.  Infinite intervals $[a,\infty),(a,\infty),(-\infty,b],(-\infty,b], (-\infty,\infty)$ with $a$ or $b$ finite.  Open intervals: $(a,b), (a,\infty), (-\infty,b), (-\infty,\infty)$.  Closed intervals: $[a,b],[a,\infty),(-\infty,b],(-\infty,\infty)$.  Half-open intervals: $[a,b), (a,b]$...

Comment: If you really are wanting to talk about a range of natural numbers, we do not generally use the bracket notation you are describing.  The set of naturals greater than or equal to $7$ is written usually as $\{7,8,9,\dots\}$ or directly via set builder notation $\{n\in\Bbb N~:~n\geq 7\}$.  We do have a common notation for intervals starting from zero as $[n]=\{0,1,2,3,\dots,n-1\}$ (*or if zero is not included as a natural in your definition as $[n]=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$*) as the prototypical $n$-element set of numbers.  You could then have $\{7,8,9,\dots\} = \Bbb N\setminus [7]$ or similar

Comment: As for naming conventions., you could I suppose use words like "intervals" or such... but would need to explicitly mention "*of naturals*" or "*of integers*" in order to make it clear that it is not an interval of real numbers.  The concept of "open" and "closed" doesn't have the same meaning in these cases though (*under the usual topology*) so don't bother attaching those words to intervals of integers.

Comment: A real-world example, my answer in a different *x*.SE where I did try to use the asked term (but is still may be confusing, please imagine all inequalities there to be the same type, e.g. sharp): https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/134938/544

Answer (score 1):

$\infty$ is not a member of the standard real numbers so $[0,\infty]$ is not usually used as it would suggest that $\infty$ was included.  $[0, \infty)$ and $(0, \infty)$ are commonly used but they are really just suggestive shorthands for set such as $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : x \ge 0 \}$.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why we call an interval 'open' or 'closed' is because such intervals are open, closed, respectively, in the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$. Since a topological space can also have clopen sets (that is, sets which are both open and closed) and sets which are neither open nor closed, some intervals are not called open/closed because they are in one of these last two cases.

Answer (score 0):

When talking about real numbers, $[0,\infty)$ is an [interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)), which might be called "unbounded" or "infinite". Because it notationally looks like $[0,1)$, some might call it a "half-open" interval. Also, because it is the complement of the open interval $(-\infty,0)$, those familiar with [topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_set) might call it a "closed" interval even though it is not written with two rectangular brackets (since $\infty$ is not a real number).

When talking about integers only, it is not common to refer to "intervals", and *especially* uncommon to use interval notation like $[3,5]$. But in a discussion of something like [order theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_theory), you might use "interval" to mean "any subset $S$ of the ordered set I'm looking at (e.g. the integers) with the property that if $a$ and $b$ are in $S$ and $a<x<b$ (in the original ordered set) then $x$ is in $S$ as well". Then things like "the set of integers greater than $5$" would be an "interval of integers".